# Allow plone site anonymous visitors to see only last modification date (but no author name)

Tags: plone

In the security control panel one can allow anonymous visitors to see "about" informations on the site pages.

Does anybody know how to only display the last modification date of a page in a Plone (4) site, without displaying the author name ?

Thanks in advance,

phep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way OOTB. You must customize the [plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline viewlet](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/b1d1ea7071c6ed606d9fbb8cee66fe892557f52f/plone/app/layout/viewlets/document_byline.pt#L16) or override the existing viewlet and provide a new one where the `documentAuthor` is omitted.

General viewlet documentation is here: http://developer.plone.org/views/viewlets.html

This tutorial about viewlet override is still valid: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customizing-main-template-viewlets/overriding-a-viewlet

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the viewlet code. I'm not sure how to introduce conditions on ACL to hide/display part of it yet. As for now, I think I will hide `documentAuthor` for everyone. Registered users will have to display the page history to reach the information. Not a big problem here.

Comment: You can add one or more of the definition you find a this document: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/no-more-global-definitions-in-templates

For example: addind the `isAnon` definition (in a `tal:condition`)  will let you possible to use something like `tal:condition="not:isAnon"` for showing the documentAuthor div only to authenticated users.